# Markers will not load on google maps API website via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am a javascript beginner and have gotten this website working locally but since I hosted it I can't get the markers to display.

The url is:

http://www.mywalkaboutsf.com/index.php

I am seeing 2 marker errors but cannot figure out why they are ony happening on the hosted site:

```
TypeError: xml is null
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

TypeError: xml is null
(?)(data=XMLHttpRequest { readyState=4, timeout=0, withCredentials=false, more...})index.php (line 251)
onreadystatechange()index.php (line 347)
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors I see in Chrome are:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined infobox.js:126
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null
```

Your database/xml is not working on the live server:

http://www.mywalkaboutsf.com/phpsearch.php

gives:
`Invalid query: Unknown column 'p.pname' in 'field list'`

Rather than valid xml.  Also, you are including infobox.js before the Google Maps API is loaded:

```
<script src="js/infobox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

needs to be after:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBBchNd66ZglMRtO0sLvolyWwMlfHU-nTU&sensor=false&libraries=places">
```